# Classifying A Matrix - matrix representation of an operator with linear operators as entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Say that one has a matrix representation of an operator `A` with differential operators as entries in the matrix `A`.

Is this a non-linear matrix? Since the differential is a linear operator and `A` is composed of linear operators, I'm leaning towards `A` being a linear operator.

If one were to take the conjugate transpose of `A`, would the differential operators be modified? I'm trying to prove that `A` is anti-hermitian, and it seems to me that the differential operators would have to be negated when `A` is conjugate-transposed in order for `A` to be anti-hermitian.

Comment: I think there are at least 2 questions here. Matrix acting on vectors is a linear operation. How do you define a non-linear matrix? With regards to hermitian operators, conjugate is usually defined as transposed and complex conjugate. Perhaps you could give an example you're working on?